# Layouts is breaking in different devices

Tags: html, css, quasar-framework

While i am zooming the site it is scratching. As I have attached the first image is without zoom. And second screen I have attached the file is after zoomin in. So while i am zooming in or out the layout is stretching so how to solve this issue in css

1.this image is without zoom and the layout is fine. Normal screen
[image]

2.Zoomed in screen
[image: Layout-27 Monitor-Connectedtosame-MacbookPro]

Please let me know how to fix this issues

Comment: First, you should always include the relevant CSS and HTML related to your questions. Second, just by looking at your images it seems like the issue is related to the background's size or position but again, you need to add your CSS and HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using units that are related to the width and height of the screen such as `vw` and `vh`. (You can also use `em` or `rem` for font). It works so much better than `px`

Just look into `vh`, `vw`, and `em` as well as the `max-width` css property. Also, try out the css property `cover`

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. i will try with that

Comment: @InayatKazi No worries.

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look and let know how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: @InayatKazi is your site online? I would like to have a look at what is causing these issues.

Comment: @InayatKazi in that case, it will be quite hard to tell you what’s wrong

Comment: actully the issue is while i am zooming the site then it is stretching

Comment: Could you please include some code (CSS and HTML).